# Is the illustration on Aliasing in C correct?

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing, function-call

I saw the link http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/cplusplus/Standards/Disk10/aliasing_c.html about aliasing in c. The program there is shown below.

```
/********************************
An example of aliasing in C.

Output:
3
3

********************************/

#include < stdio.h >

int main()

{

   int G_Var = 2;

   /* call SomeFunction with the Global Variable as a parameter */

   SomeFunction(G_Var); 

   return 0;
}

/* InputVar becomes an alias fo G_Var */

void SomeFunction(int &InputVar)
{

   int G_Var;
   int InputVar;

   /* Global Variable is set to new value */

   G_Var = InputVar + 1;       

   /* Equivalent to G_Var = G_Var + 1 */

   printf("%i\n", InputVar);

   printf("%i\n", G_Var);

}
```

Is the code correct and is working according to what is commented in the code?

Comment: This seems to be C for the most part. But this `void SomeFunction(int &InputVar)` is not. Please double check that there is no typo or copy-paste mistake in your question.

Comment: Apart from that, please give details on what makes you doubt. As is, your question lacks focus on a specific problem you want to discuss. Also, please add your observations when trying to compile and run the code. Do your observations match or not?

Comment: The shown code (C or not) would be cleaner with a prototype before main. You really need to be more specific about what of the weirdnesses you want to discuss.

Comment: @Yunnosch But the entire code is just completely wrong, not just specific parts. Another university comp science horror story - the people who wrote this code need to lose their jobs before they cause more harm.

Comment: @Lundin I agree. However, while I'd accept the code mostly as very questionable (even non-compilable) C, the one line is a C++ concept and stands out in its level of not being C.

Comment: @Lundin "*the people who wrote this code need to lose their jobs before they cause more harm.*" - Drastic words, but entirely correct. I fully agree with that part and wonder how the **9** cited people didn't saw any issue.

Comment: Looking at the URL it becomes obvious that this is about C++, so the most glaring problem (the `&`)  is less of one. But then describing this as "C" turns into one to replace it. Seriously, if you teach a language then you should at least be clear about which one. Welcome to "English as a foreign language", lets discuss our first verb together "avoir".

Comment: If anyone would like to complain about how a self-proposed university can use such purely defective examples: deptsec@cs.uregina.ca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever wrote the link was severely incompetent and shouldn't be teaching C. They should rather enlist in a beginner's class themselves.

- `int G_Var = 2;` is *not* a global variable, it is a local one with automatic storage duration. Both the one in main() and the one inside the function.
- The code posted is C++, not C. C does not have references.
- The term alias/aliasing refers to when several pointers (or C++ references) may be assumed to point at the same memory location.
- `int InputVar;` in the function conflicts with the parameter name so the code doesn't make any sense. In case there were no name conflict, the variable would be uninitialized and then used, which would be senseless.

> Is the code correct and is working according to what is commented in the code?

Whoever wrote this example was so confused that it's really hard to be telling what they are trying to teach, or in which language for that matter. The code does not compile for multiple fundamental reasons. Just forget about this mess.

Comment: I think a more apt description than “alias/aliasing refers to when several pointers” for the type of aliasing involved here is something along the lines of “an object is accessed with multiple lvalues of incompatible types.” `int i = 3; float f = *(float *)ix;` is aliasing even though one access is via name and one is via pointer. And `union { int i; float f; } x = {3}; x.f;` has no pointers at all. Accessing via multiple pointers of the same type is also a kind of aliasing, although then that complicated description for the `restrict` keyword comes into play to distinguish unrelated pointers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In this case, maybe start with learning basic things like knowing which programming language we are coding in, how functions and variables work, how to include a header file...

Answer (score 2):

Four things to say:

1. C does not have C++-kind of aliases/references. It is a C++ feature only.

   So,

   ```
   /* InputVar becomes an alias fo G_Var */

    void SomeFunction(int &InputVar)
   ```

   is wrong.
2. `G_Var` is not a global variable. You declare it two times to be local to `main` and `SomeFunction`. If you want to declare `G_Var` as global variable it has to be declared *once* at global scope, not inside of a function, and only access it by its name, not declaring its type twice.

   But beside that the use of global variables is deprecated. Rather use parameter passing.
3. `SomeFunction()` isn't declared before the call to it in `main()`. Usually this would give you a diagnostic as the compiler don't know what `SomeFunction()` is.
4. `InputVar` is used as reference parameter, but also declared twice in `SomeFunction`. Here is a conflict.

I guess you never compiled this code before asking, which is a fault. It would have answered many questions of yours including the main one.

> "*Is the illustration on Aliasing in C correct?*"
>
> "*Is the code correct and is working according to what is commented in the code?*"

No, it isn't. The whole code is defective.

It gives the impression that the authors didn't knew how to either write correct C nor C++ code.

Comment: C does have the concept of aliasing. Even though not mentioned as a formal term, the standard refers to chapter 6.5 for aliasing - meaning pointer aliasing. It's far from a beginner topic, however.

Comment: And the OP clearly got the code from "Copyright 2000 Department of Computer Science, University of Regina". Apparently yet another Internet fake university located in someone's basement.

Comment: @Lundin I still wonder how **9** cited people from the source can't see any issues in this code.

Comment: Or why they thought this code was so fantastic that they needed to copyright it... I'm pretty darn sure nobody would want to steal it.

Comment: @Lundin It's probably to prevent it from be taken as subject for a comedy/standup  performance/movie.